Dell Inspiron 1501 loses wireless after rebooting I'm running Lububtu 24.04
I have a Dell Inspiron 1505 with Lubuntu 24.04. My wireless card does not work. After much reading online for possible solutions, I did find a fix.
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt install linux firmware
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe b43
sudo rfkill all

Suddenly the wireless is working. Until I reboot. How do I make this permanent?
